# same table, 1 field to 2 field query

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables: 1st holds employees (of ones in any position) and the 2nd holds manager employee relations with id numbers.

I want to write a query like

```
1st field: name(employee), 
2nd field: name(manager)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No nested queries required, just use standard joins:

```
select e.*, m.*
from
  employee e
    left join employee_managers em
      on e.id = em.emp_id
    left join employee m
      on m.id = em.man_id
```

Each row will contain all fields of `employee` (possibly several rows for one employee if it has several associated managers) and all fields of his corresponding manager (or `NULL`s if employee has no manager).

Comment: yes, my solution was right above, ems mysql manager did it for me by chance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with one table:

```
 Employee
 --------
 EmployeeId int
 Name varchar(50)
 ManagerId int
```

`ManagerId` points to the manager's entry in the same table.  The CEO will have a ManagerId of `null`.  An example table definition:

```
create table Employees (
  EmployeeId int auto_increment primary key
, Name varchar(50)
, ManagerId int
, foreign key (ManagerId) references Employees(EmployeeId)
);
```

With some example data:

```
insert into Employees (Name) select 'The Chief';
insert into Employees (Name, ManagerId) select 'Grunt 1', 
    (select EmployeeId from Employees where Name = 'The Chief');
insert into Employees (Name, ManagerId) select 'Grunt 2', 
    (select EmployeeId from Employees where Name = 'The Chief');
insert into Employees (Name, ManagerId) select 'Secretary', 
    (select EmployeeId from Employees where Name = 'The Chief');
```

To find the name of the second Grunt's manager, you could query like:

```
select mgr.Name
from Employees mgr
inner join Employees grunt
on grunt.managerid = mgr.employeeid
where grunt.name = 'Grunt 2';
```

Comment: @incarnate: Right.... misread the question.  Your answer already has the right solution I'll vote for it

Comment: yours is still a good solution if they want to refactor their DB :-) +1 for the effort.